# Get response from POST request to web.py wrapper around neural network

Tags: python, ajax, neural-network, web.py

After reading through the first three chapters of [Michael Nielson's excellent free book on neural networks](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com), I wanted to try out a canvas based web interface to see how well it would perform on my own hand-written input. The result is [this branch](https://github.com/tlehman/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/tree/web-interface) on his forked example code repo. It includes a square canvas that users can sketch out digits, and then it does an XHR POST to a web.py wrapper to the network.

The problem I am having is with web.py, in particular:

```
class recognize:
    def POST(self, name):
        # read in posted base64 data, assume PNG, convert to greyscale
        data = web.data()
        file = cStringIO.StringIO(urllib.urlopen(data).read())
        img = Image.open(file).convert('L')
        # resize to 28x28
        img.thumbnail((28,28), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        # convert to vector
        vec = np.asarray(img).reshape((28*28,1)).astype(float)
        # feed foward through neural network
        digit = net.recognize(vec)
        print digit
        return digit
```

The last line doesn't seem to matter, I can't get the `digit` in the HTTP response to my javascript client. Is there some other way I should be putting the `digit` into the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python side is fine, you actually need to register a callback on the XMLHttpRequest in your index.html in order to capture the response from recognize

```
function exportImage() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
         alert(xhr.responseText) //capture digit here and do something with it
      }
  };
  xhr.open("POST", "//localhost:8080/recognize", true);
  xhr.send(canvas.toDataURL());
}
```